# $\overline{A} B C + A B \overline{C} \stackrel{?}{=} \overline{A} B + B \overline{C}$

Tags: logic, algebraic-logic

I am trying to simplify (minimise) a Boolean expression but I can't seem to get the result I am supposed to. I even ran into a pretty bad contradiction and I have no idea what's wrong...

This is my expression:

*(spacing between letters means multiplication (AND) and the $+$ operator means addition (OR))*

> $$ \mathrm{F}2 = \overline{A} \: \overline{B} \: \overline{C} + \overline{A} B \overline{C} + \overline{A} B C + A B \overline{C} $$

This is the way I simplified it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{F}2 &= \overline{A} \: \overline{B} \: \overline{C} + \overline{A} B \overline{C} + \overline{A} B C + A B \overline{C} = \\
&= \overline{A} (\overline{B} \: \overline{C} + B \overline{C} + B C) + A B \overline{C} = \\
&= \overline{A} (\overline{C} (\overline{B} + B) + B C) + A B \overline{C}) = \\
&= \overline{A} (\overline{C} + B C) + A B \overline{C} = \\
&= \boxed{\overline{A} \: \overline{C} + \overline{A} B C + A B \overline{C}}
\end{aligned}
$$

However, if I enter the expression into a calculator, such as *Logic Friday 1,* I get this:

[image: Logic Friday 1 minimising expression]

So basically it says the simplified expression should be

$$ \mathrm{F}2 = \boxed{\overline{A} B + \overline{A} \: \overline{C} + B \overline{C}} $$

But this would mean, looking at the two boxed (supposedly equal) expressions, that (since $\overline{A} \: \overline{C}$ is present in both)

> $$ \overline{A} B C + A B \overline{C} = \overline{A} B + B \overline{C} $$

Which is quite impossible... Just take a look at this MS Office Excel table illustrating how they are different:

[image: Excel truth table]

**So what is going on here?**

Could anybody please explain? :/

Comment: you can't eliminate $\overline{A} \: \overline{C}$ just because they are present in both parts, you can see from your truth table that if you add $\overline{A} \: \overline{C}$ you will get 1 for LHS.

Comment: @Vasya Oh... So basically this doesn't work like regular equation? From $a + b + c = a + d + e$ it does not follow that $b + c = d + e$?

Comment: of course not  $A + T=B + T$ does not mean $A=B$, in logic, right?

Comment: @Vasya Oh my gosh. Of course, how stupid of me... Would you please add your answer as an actual *answer* to the question so that I can select it as the best answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use logic operations we can't eliminate $\overline{A}\:\overline{C}$ just because they are present in both parts of the equation. $\overline{A}BC+AB\overline{C}+\overline{A}\:\overline{C}=1$ when $A=C=0$ and $B=1$. But  $\overline{A}BC+AB\overline{C}=0$ for the same values of $A, B, C$